# how to remove space from firebase search query

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am doing a project where firebase search query is using,in firebase database i created many data,while using the search query some of them is not getting. I checked for problems and find that some of the data contain a  before the content start.I want to know how to avoid the space in firebase search query.

````
   ``` Query firebaseSearchQuery = reference.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff"); ```
````

I want to know how to avoid the spaces in firebase database.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trim()` to remove space:

```
String searchedText = searchText.trim();
Query firebaseSearchQuery = reference.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchedText ).endAt(searchedText + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: no difference,in this case title which begin with <space> is not listing,any other methods?

Comment: `trim()` removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of the word, so if searchText for example is equal to `"hello   "` , it will remove the space at the end..

Comment: In your case, where do you have space, if you have in your database then you need to fix that first... then you can do a query without space..

Comment: If in the database you have `title: Course Math`, no its not wrong.. if the user in the search wrote `math` then it should find that title.

Comment: yes,the problem is in my database ,but there is a lot of data,i can't edit all of them,that is why i'm trying to avoid the space...

Comment: you can add `trim()` to everything before adding to the database, so you would have in the database `title:coursemath` then if someone wrote math it will appear